# How to enable the Android Studio Video Capturing

Tags: android, video-capture

I'm using Android Studio v1.1.0. I want to capture a video of my phone's screen when launching the app via the 'Run App' command. I've found the appropriate button in the 'DDMS' tab, but it's grayed out.

I've tried running the app both on a physical device running 4.1.2 and on a virtual device, but the button is grayed out every time. Am I missing something? What are the conditions to capture a video using this method?

Comment: Does `adb shell screenrecord` work?

Comment: No `/system/bin/sh: screenrecord: not found`. I´ve changed to the platform-tools folder at sdk and entered the following command: `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4`

Comment: I´ve to say that my phone uses Android 4.1.2. Is this the reason, why I can´t capture the screen via Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah, I thought video capture was 4.4 and up?

Comment: Here's the changelog for that feature, I don't see any OS version restrictions: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released

Comment: Android Studio is just running screenrecord, which wasn't part of Android until the 4.4 release.